# Best practice to keep track of indexes for a number of lists

Tags: c#

So basically I have a number of lists of foos.

```
List<List<foo>> listOfFooLists;
```

The user can choose a time with a slider and all values of all the lists, which timestamps are smaller then the selected time, are summed up.
In order to save performance when the user changes the time, I want to keep track of the indexes so I can only sum up (or substract) the values which haven't been added yet.

```
public class foo
{
    float someValue;
    DateTime someTimestamp;
}
```

What's the best way to somehow keep track of the indexes and link them to their respective list.
I hope I made my problem somehow clear...
Thanks in advance

*Edit: Yes, the Lists are sorted by timestamp.

Anyway, this was just an example. In my real project the operations are more expensive than just summing up the values.

For now the list can't grow, but if they could grow, the new items would be added on the end.

Comment: Are the items in the lists sorted by `someTimestamp`?

Comment: How many `foo`s you keep in that lists? 10000000000? If much less, then why do you want to optimize such simple things?

Comment: Can lists grow after the user starts using the slider? And if they can, are the new items added only on the end of lists?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is large enough that you'll see significant performance hits, it may be worth it to keep track of that information. As an example of your options, you could make a new struct to replace the list of lists. This struct can contain an additional parameter to track the values that have been processed already. A rough example:

```
public struct ListTracker  
{  
    public List<foo> bar;
    public bool isAdded;
}

List<ListTracker> tracker;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Actually I need to know up to which item I have added to the sum,
so I would have added an int index instead of a bool.
However, wouldn't this be a violation of the single responsibility principle?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your intention is. Is the int +1 per element or a variable amount?